# Reading two column data from a file

Tags: c#

I want to read the text file data which are coordinates of the centre of the circle.

I am using below code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nCols = 301;
    int nRows = 301;

    string[] text1 = File.ReadAllLines("test1.txt");

    for (int row = 0; row < text1.Length; row++)
    {
        string[] textCols = text1[row].Split(' ');
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Value at Cell [{0}, {1}] : {2}", row, col, textCols[col]));                
        }
    }
}
```

Irrespective of number of values my file has, The loop is always showing 6 by 6 matrix values.

I am unable to understand the problem. Please help

Comment: can you post your file here?

Comment: Please show your input and output values to create a [mcve]. Try to debug and inspect `text1` ... I suspect you starting out with something different than you think. Possible culprit could be inconsistent line endings.

Comment: What is the *file content*, please? Please, provide at least **7** top rows

Comment: Why  `nCols = 301`? It seems it should be ` nCols = 2`

Comment: why    col < 2     it should    col < textCols.Length      | can you post out put you are getting and output you want

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that your two numbers are separated by a single space?

Anyway, this should work

```
 using (StreamReader reader = OpenText("test1.txt"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, "[0-9]+");
                        foreach (var match in matches)
                        {
                            //do something...
                            Debug.WriteLine("point " + match);

                        }
                    }
                }
```